# OSPF: Migrating Quagga to BIRD

Tags: debian, bird, quagga, ospf

I need/want to migrate from Quagga to BIRD after several Quagga hiccups, namely [Quagga stopped working after updates in Stretch](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/331664/quagga-stopped-working-after-updates-in-stretch/331665).

BIRD is also more flexible and modern.

I have my OSPF BIND anycast configuration in Quagga and would like to setup the OSPF service in a way similar on BIRD.

What to do?

My `/etc/quagga/ospfd.conf` is:

```
!
! Zebra configuration saved from vty
!   2011/03/22 21:17:11
!
hostname dns
password 8 xxxxxxx
enable password 8 xxxxxxx
log stdout
service password-encryption
!
!
!
interface dummy0
 ip ospf cost 100
!
interface dummy1
 ip ospf cost 500
!
interface dummy2
 ip ospf cost 1000
!
interface dummy3
 ip ospf cost 900
!
interface eth0
 ip ospf authentication message-digest
 ip ospf message-digest-key 5 md5 MySecretPassword
 ip ospf cost 1000
!
interface eth1
 ip ospf cost 1000
!
interface lo
!
router ospf
 ospf router-id 1.1.1.1
 auto-cost reference-bandwidth 10000
 network 1.1.1.0/22 area 0.0.0.0
 network 2.2.2.2/32 area 0.0.0.0
 network 3.3.3.3/32 area 0.0.0.0
 network 4.4.4.4/32 area 0.0.0.0
 network 5.5.5.5/32 area 0.0.0.0
 area 0 filter-list prefix AREA_1_OUT out
!
ip prefix-list AREA_1_OUT seq 5 permit 2.2.2.2/32
ip prefix-list AREA_1_OUT seq 10 permit 3.3.3.3/32
ip prefix-list AREA_1_OUT seq 15 permit 4.4.4.4/32
ip prefix-list AREA_1_OUT seq 20 permit 5.5.5.5/32
ip prefix-list AREA_1_OUT seq 25 deny any
!
line vty
!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After solving the problems described here [OSPF md5 encryption from Quagga to BIRD](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381954/ospf-md-5-encryption-from-quagga-to-bird) and in [OSPF route costs in BIRD](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381905/ospf-route-costs-in-bird) , the rest of the migration is relatively easy.

To have an equivalent service, the steps are:

```
sudo dpkg --purge quagga
sudo apt-get install bird
sudo chkconfig bird6 off
sudo service bird6 stop
```

Then there is a need to create the setup in `/etc/bird/bird.conf` as:

```
#
router id 1.1.1.1;

# The Device protocol is not a real routing protocol. It doesn't generate any
# routes and it only serves as a module for getting information about network
# interfaces from the kernel.
protocol device {
    scan time 10;
}

protocol ospf {
        tick 2;
        rfc1583compat yes;

        area 0.0.0.0 {

            networks {
                1.1.1.0/22;
            };
            stubnet 2.2.2.2/32 {
                 cost 100;
            };
            stubnet 3.3.3.3/32 {
                 cost 500;  
            };
            stubnet 4.4.4.4/32 {
                 cost 1000;
            };
            stubnet 5.5.5.5/32 {
                 cost 900;
            };
            interface "eth0" {
                cost 1000;
                password "MySecretPassword" {
                    id 5;
                };
                authentication cryptographic; 
            };

            interface "dummy0" {
                stub;
            };
            interface "dummy1" {
                stub;
            };
            interface "dummy2" {
                stub;
            };
            interface "dummy3" {
                stub;
            };

        };
}
```

After modifying the configuration:

```
sudo service bird restart
```

To check for the service on the local server:

```
sudo birdc
```

and then

```
show status
```

and

```
show ospf
```

and

```
show ospf state
```

and

```
show ospf neighbors
```

P.S. I did not find a straightforward document, and did not find much about Quagga coexisting and migrating to BIRD, and decided to document it here.

I did not migrate all my Quagga servers/OSPF nodes at once, because both configurations are similar, and talk with each other (via the OSPF protocol obviously).

See also [OSPF import route filter for BIRD](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382120/ospf-route-filter-for-bird)