# Porting OSPF route filter rule for BIRD

Tags: bird, ospf

I have an anycast setup for DNS using BIRD [OSPF: Migrating Quagga to BIRD](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381962/ospf-migrating-quagga-to-bird)

However, using "show routes" in the `birdc` command I see lots of OSPF learned routes from our internal network.

As it is, in this anycast setup (and normally), there is only a need to announce routes, and not to receive them.

How to create a filter in BIRD to ignore the OSPF routes?

My OSPF setup is this one:

```
 protocol ospf {
        tick 2;
        rfc1583compat yes;

        area 0.0.0.0 {

            networks {
                1.1.1.0/22;
            };
            stubnet 2.2.2.2/32 {
                 cost 100;
            };
            stubnet 3.3.3.3/32 {
                 cost 500;  
            };
            stubnet 4.4.4.4/32 {
                 cost 1000;
            };
            stubnet 5.5.5.5/32 {
                 cost 900;
            };
            interface "eth0" {
                cost 1000;
                password "MySecretPassword" {
                    id 5;
                };
                authentication cryptographic; 
            };

            interface "dummy0" {
                stub;
            };
            interface "dummy1" {
                stub;
            };
            interface "dummy2" {
                stub;
            };
            interface "dummy3" {
                stub;
            };

        };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here, [How redistribute routes from kernel table to OSPF protocol?](http://bird.network.cz/pipermail/bird-users/2012-February/007530.html), and modified the OSPF configuration for creating the filter for dropping the routes learned from OSPF.

The modification will be done accordingly to all the elements of the *anycast* DNS cluster.

Take heed for the import_OSPF filter added in the modified OSPF config.

```
filter import_OSPF {
    reject;
}

protocol ospf {
        tick 2;
        rfc1583compat yes;

        import filter import_OSPF;
        area 0.0.0.0 {

            networks {
                1.1.1.0/22;
            };
            stubnet 2.2.2.2/32 {
                 cost 100;
            };
            stubnet 3.3.3.3/32 {
                 cost 500;  
            };
            stubnet 4.4.4.4/32 {
                 cost 1000;
            };
            stubnet 5.5.5.5/32 {
                 cost 900;
            };
            interface "eth0" {
                cost 1000;
                password "MySecretPassword" {
                    id 5;
                };
                authentication cryptographic; 
            };

            interface "dummy0" {
                stub;
            };
            interface "dummy1" {
                stub;
            };
            interface "dummy2" {
                stub;
            };
            interface "dummy3" {
                stub;
            };

        };
}
```

After restarting BIRD, the "show route" diagnostic command in `birdc` already does not show any imported OSPF routes, as it is intended.